# sed. Замена сложной строки

Tags: bash, sed

В файле есть строки типа:

AAA|AaaaA = "aaa -x 1"

BBB|BbbbB = "bbb -y 1"

которые нужно заменить на:

AAA|AaaaA = "aaa -y 1"

BBB|BbbbB = "bbb -x 1"

Не получается заставить sed прочитать всю строку.

Планируется выполнять через скрипт, в качестве строк выступают переменные. Файлов таких много, поэтому выглядит так:

for i in $files

do

sed $i

done

Comment: Т.е. надо менять нечто от знака `-` до `пробел 1` ?

Comment: абсолютно непонятно, в чём состоит ваша проблема, и какой ответ вы хотите получить.

Comment: "Т.е. надо менять нечто от знака - до пробел 1" именно

Comment: Проблема в том, что нельзя менять только -x на -y, потому что получится два -y, которые потом поменяются на -x (при втором проходе скрипта). Поэтому надо привязывать к дополнительным данным, в моем случае целиком к строке, она уникальна. Но не получается эту строку передать в sed, он не понимает все пробелы кавычки и дефисы, экранировать всю строку геморно, хочется седу скармливать переменную. Вот и вопрос, как?

Comment: @SebastianPereiro можно и не привязывать. можно сделать за один проход скрипта, `sed 's/-x/-y/;s/-y/-x/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно заменить x на y  и наоборот, можно сделать проще:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Может быть использовать awk? Ну например в случае замены x на y и наоборот получается нечто вроде

```
awk '{if ($4 == "-x") print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " -y " $5;if ($4 == "-y") print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " -x " $5}' <файл>
```

По поводу двойного прохода sed. Можно в первом проходе заменять x или y на какую-нибудь уникальную сигнатуру, например y на YyYy, x на XxXx, во втором проходе sed не путаясь заменит YyYy на x, XxXx на y.

```
sed -e 's/\(^[A-Z]\{3\}|[A-Za-z]\{5\} = "[a-z]\{3\} -\)y\( 1"$\)/\1YyYy\2/g'
```

Итого будет 4 прохода: 2 подготовительных по x и y, и два финальных по сигнатурам.

Comment: Спасибо, хороший вариант, но я сделал в лоб - вписал целиком строку в sed

Comment: В sed можно через точку с запятой давать сразу несколько команд замены за один проход. А при желании можно даже IF организовать

Comment: Можно, но... Для IF-THEN наверное надо запорочиться с метками и t. ИМХО наряду с кортежированием команд это делает синтаксис еще более нечитаемым. При использовании в баш предпочитаю разделять на атомарно-смысловые операции сопровождая коментариями... Иначе сам же через пару месяцев сломаю себе глаза.